# Bootstrap carousel not working on business catalyst hosted site

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, business-catalyst

I used the same code below in dreamweaver.  In a local hosted environment, it works fine.  However, if I put exactly same code in Business Catalyst server, it cannot show the images.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script> $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            //options here
            });
        });
        </script> 
    </head>



     <body>
         <div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>
              <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <div class="item active"><a href="#"><img src="image/Gold_960x560.png" alt="First slide image" class="center-block"></a>
                      <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h3>First slide Heading</h3>
                          <p>First slide Caption</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item"><a href="#"><img src="image/silver_960x560.png" alt="Second slide image" class="center-block"></a>
                      <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h3>Second slide Heading</h3>
                          <p>Second slide Caption</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item"><a href="#"><img src="image/orchid_960x560.png" alt="Third slide image" class="center-block"></a>
                      <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h3>Third slide Heading</h3>
                          <p>Third slide Caption</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>.
                  </a>
              </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In production... are you sure your image paths are correct... "image/Gold_960x560.png" or "../image/Gold_960x560.png" etc?

Comment: And can you add a pic of the result?

Comment: Yes, I had double check the path.

Comment: Yes, in other div, pic display normal.

Comment: So what actually happens? "it cannot show images proper" is not very descriptive

Comment: Buttons, function are In normal, for the ping, Safari just display a box with "?", in Chrome, alt can display, but not the png.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen images and files not render correctly in BC without the `/` in front of them. Try adding the `/` in front of your image path and see if they render. IE:

```
src="/image/Gold_960x560.png"
```

If they still do not render, be sure they are uploaded to the server and the path is correct.

You commented:

> ...for the ping, Safari just display a box with "?", in Chrome, alt can display, but not the png.

You will see this when an image isn't loading.